# Delphi : multiply integer with real number(newbie)

Tags: delphi, integer

I want to multiply an `integer` with `real` number. This is my code:

```
interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;
 num ,sumadh,sumadist,corectiah :integer;
 cs,cf,dist,deltahprim,deltah,H:Array of integer;
 corectiatest,cotareper:integer;
 kh  :real;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;    
begin
  num := 3;
  SetLength(cs, num);
  SetLength(cf, num);
  SetLength(dist, num);
  SetLength(deltahprim, num);
  SetLength(H, num);

  sumadh := 0;
  sumadist := 0;
  cotareper := StrtoInt(InputBox('Cota reper nivelment',
    'Valoare cota in cm', '0'));
  for i := 1 to num do
  begin
    cs[i] := StrtoInt(InputBox('Niveleul nr' + Inttostr(i),
      'Citire spate (cm)', '0'));

    cf[i] := StrtoInt(InputBox('Niveleul nr' + Inttostr(i),
      'Citire fata(cm)', '0'));

    dist[i] := StrtoInt(InputBox('Niveleul nr' + Inttostr(i),
      'Distanta intre mire(cm)', '0'));

    deltahprim[i] := cs[i] - cf[i];
    sumadh := sumadh + deltahprim[i];
    sumadist := sumadist + dist[i];
  end;

  corectiah := -sumadh;
  kh := corectiah / sumadist;

  ShowMessage('Suma deltah = ' + Inttostr(sumadh));
  ShowMessage('Suma distantelor este = ' + Inttostr(sumadist));
  ShowMessage('Corectia este = ' + Inttostr(corectiah));
  ShowMessage('Cota reper este = ' + Inttostr(cotareper));

  for i := 1 to num do
  begin

    deltah[i] := deltahprim[i] + kh * dist[i];
    ShowMessage('delta h compensat = ' + Inttostr(deltah[i]));

  end;
end;

end.
```

The variable `kh` will be something like `0.0005` and it needs to get multiplied with `dist[i]`. But I cannot run the code. I'm getting the following error message:

> incompatible types integer and double.

Is there any integer-to-real function? E.g. something like `InttoReal`?

Answer (score 3):

> incompatible types integer and double

You must convert the multiplication of the integer and the float value to an integer value, when assigning to an integer.

Use

```
deltah[i] := deltahprim[i] + Round(kh * dist[i]);  // Or Trunc(kh * Dist[i]);
```

A float multiplied with an integer promotes the integer to a float during the multiplication. The result is a float value, and it is the programmers duty to convert it back to an integer (when assigned to an integer), since the compiler cannot evaluate the intention of the multiplication.

[Round()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Round) and [Trunc()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Trunc) usually covers the conversion needs.

---

If the intention was to keep as much relevant precision as possible, just declare `deltah` as an array of double instead (skipping the round/trunc).

---

**Other problems in code:**

- You have to allocate the `deltah` array with `SetLength()`. This is the probable cause of your exception as mentioned in comments.
- All loops must go from zero to num-1, since dynamic arrays starts with zero index.

---

Turn on range checking and use the debugger to single step your code. The IDE is a resourceful tool to find those errors.

Comment: Yes(need atleast 4-5 decimals) but declaring deltah as array didn't let me do deltah[i] as far as I remember , or I have to declare both real numbers ? Also you happen to know what could cause thise error ? imgur.com/IpbXgjP Works untill ShowMessage('Cota reper este = '+IntToStr(cotareper)); then crashes for some reason

Comment: The exception comes from your `deltah` array not being allocated with SetLength().

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, you just multiply.

```
var
  i: integer;
  r: real;
  p: real;
begin
  p:= r * i;
end;
```

Just make sure that you store the result in a floating point variable.

If you want to store the result in an integer, you'll have to do some rounding, or truncating.

```
var
  i: integer;
  r: real;
  pi: integer;
begin
  pi:= round(r * i);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

deltah is an Array of integer and you are trying to get a float calculation, so you have to change the type of the deltah array to array of double

```
deltah: array of double;

deltah[i]:=(deltahprim[i]+kh*dist[i]);
ShowMessage('delta h compensat = '+FloatToStr(deltah[i]));
```

Comment: Thanks I think it worked but when i try to test it , it crashes , you know what could be the cause ? http://imgur.com/IpbXgjP  Works untill ShowMessage('Cota reper este = '+IntToStr(cotareper)); then crashes for some reason.

Comment: The first element of the array is index zero, not one.  Try 0 to Num-1 instead of 1 to Num.  Or better low(A) to high(A)